# winapi CreateWindowEx -> create button with user system styles?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, button

I want to make a button that looks just like the OK button when you go My Computer -> Help -> About Windows.

I am creating a button like this:

```
hButton = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Text"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 10, 10, 30, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

But it looks like a rough square and does not use the windows styles that the user has selected. I guess I should be using some sort of window class but I am unsure what class?

Answer (score 8):

You want to use version 6 of the common controls library.  To do this you need to add an application manifest to your executable.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997646.aspx) on how to do that.

Comment: The MSDN link apparently has disappeared - try this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try running [ControlSpy](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0798/controlspy.aspx) which will allow you to try out different styles quickly.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can just somehow specify to use the default style being used by the system? Is style the right word? Style seems to be a type of button, not really anything to do with its visual appearance.

Comment: these are two distinct concepts: control style and visual theme. your question seem to relate more to visual theme.