# How to create win7 style button using CreateWindowEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, button, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [winapi CreateWindowEx -> create button with user system styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647202/winapi-createwindowex-create-button-with-user-system-styles)

Hi,
I am kinda new to WinAPI and C++ and I am using Visual Studio 2010. I want to create some buttons in the main window. So there are two questions:

1) can I use a dialog window created with resource editor as a main window so that I wouldnt have to create all controls "by hand" in the "post-WM_CREATE message" section?

2) (If I cant use resource script made window with buttons as a main window) When I "hand make" button using CreateWindowEx like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:

    {
    HFONT buttonFont = CreateFont(-11, 0, 0, 0, 400, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 1, 400, 0, 0, 0, fontButtonFont);
    HWND bMainOK = CreateWindowEx(
        0, 
        WC_BUTTON, 
        szOkButton, 
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
        24, 200, 75, 23, 
        hWnd, 
        0, 
        hInst, 
        0);
    SendMessage(bMainOK, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)buttonFont, FALSE);
    }
```

I get very ugly oldstyle button. How do I make it look like Win7/Vista button? Or better how do I make it behave as system style setting says (when using XP get XP style button, when using Vista get Vista style button etc.)?

Thanks

Comment: An easy way for unmanaged c++ is to simply add to following code to a cpp:

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link a manifest to your app that specifies v6 common controls. Websearch will do the rest for you.